Extrude symmetrically along an axis
I want to extrude the following two faces symmetrically along the X axis (one to the right and the other to the left):

When selecting only one of the faces and clicking E and then X I get the desired result for that side:

But doing so while selecting both faces drags both of them to the same side:

I have tried Alt+E and then clicking "Extrude Individual faces", but then although symmetrical, it seems I have no control of extruding to a single axis (I tried clicking E after "Extrude Individual faces" but it did nothing):

Is there a way to extrude both faces symmetrically on the X axis?
(I'd wish to avoid cutting the model into a half and then mirror it.)

F3 > Extrude along Normals

I get the same result as with "Extrude Individual Faces", I would like to extrude along the X axis

Extrude one of the faces along the X axis and then select the other face and press Shift+R to do the same. Then press F9 to bring up the pop up window and change the positive X value to the negative
You can also select both and press E+S+X to extrude and immediately scale them along the X axis but you'll have to scale them down individually to for them to have a similar angle as before
Tbh, it's a lot faster for you to use a mirror modifier or symmetrize the mesh by going to mesh->symmetrize

I didn't manage to follow the first option, when selecting the other face should the first face be selected too?
Do I need to extrude the second face as well before the Shift+X?

@Eule No, you extrude the first face along the X axis and then just select only the other face and press Shift+R. (I wrote Shift+x before, that was wrong)
